# R to create a data frame a specific way

Tags: r

I am trying to create a data frame and in the column of time I need to have each time written 1 time before the next date. For example:

```
1983-01-01
1983-01-01
1983-01-01
1983-01-01
1983-01-02
1983-01-02
```

etc.

for 10 years.

I used this command, but I don't have the needed format.

```
data=data.frame(date=as.Date("1983-01-01") +seq(n))
head(data)
        date
1 1983-01-02
2 1983-01-03
3 1983-01-04
4 1983-01-05
5 1983-01-06
6 1983-01-07
```

Comment: the text not reproduced correctly because dates are in one colomn

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. You want each date to be repeated 4 times? I.e., some thing like `date <- as.Date("1983-01-01") + seq(n);
data <- data.frame(rep(date, each = 4))
` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to create the data frame:

```
library(zoo)
start_date <- as.Date("1983-01-01")
stop_date <- as.Date(as.yearmon(start_date) + 10) - 1
# [1] "1992-12-31"
dat <- data.frame(date = rep(seq(start_date, stop_date, by = 1), each = 4))
```

*Update* (based on comment):

```
dates <- lapply(seq(0, 9), function(x) 
  rep(as.Date((as.yearmon(start_date) + x) + (0:11)/12), each = 3) + c(0,10,20))
dat <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dates, 
                             function(x) data.frame(date = rep(x, each = 4))))
```

Comment: thank you Sven and David, this helped solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Sven, I noticed the data is decadal (10 days average) rather than daily therefor, each month has 3 dates ex: 1983=01=01 1993-01-11 1983-1983-21 and the 1983-02-01 etc. Is this doable as per your scripts for 10 years

Comment: @user3290596: please accept this answer so as to mark the question as resolved. I've downvoted the original post, happy to undownvote if you can do the above.